# Freeing the temp node when adding to a linkedlist

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc, free

I have a function called `addMod` that, when called, adds a node to a certain index of an array of `Module` struct LinkedLists called `modules` contained within a `System` struct. A `Module` struct has a string field, two int fields, and a pointer to the next `Module`, the first three fields being initialized according to arguments provided in `addMod`. `addMod` roughly looks like this:

```
int addMod(System *system, const char *text, int num1, int num2, int index) {
    Module *temp = malloc(sizeof(Module));
    Module *current;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if ([any of the constructors are invalid]) return 0;

    temp->text = malloc(strlen(text)+1);
    strcpy(temp->text, text);
    temp->num1 = num1; temp->num2 = num2;

    if (!system->modules[index]) {
        system->modules[index] = temp; //If there are no modules in the LinkedList at the given index, makes the head = temp.
    }
    else {
        if (system->compare(temp, system->modules[index]) <= 0) { //compare is a func pointer field of system that compares two Modules to see in what order they should be. Here, we check if temp should become the head of modules[index].
            temp->next = system->modules[index]; //Assigns the current head as the module following temp.
            system->modules[index] = temp; //Makes temp the current head.
        }
        else {
            current = system->modules[index];
            while (current->next && system->compare(temp, current->next) > 0) { //While current isn't the last node in the LinkedList and temp comes after the node after current
                current = current->next;
             }
            temp->next = current->next; //Adds temp in between current and current->next.
            current->next = temp;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

All of the above works as expected, except when printing the contents of `system`, the console indicates there's a memory leak that I'm assuming is because I fail to properly free `temp` based on what valgrind tells me. My problem is not knowing where to free it- it seems anywhere I put it causes a segfault after printing the contents. From my understanding, I have to make sure that no other variables are depending upon the value being held by `temp`, but I can't seem to find a way to do that considering every possible ending of my if statement leads to assigning `temp` to a node within `modules`. Putting `free(temp)` between the logic and `return 1` also yields a segfault, I'm assuming because I often malloc `temp` again when calling `addMod` multiple times in succession.

In summary, to add a new node to a LinkedList that may or may not be populated, in which this new node may be inserted in any arbitrary position in the LinkedList, I have to allocate memory to a temporary node so that I can insert it later. Where do I free this allocated memory once I have successfully inserted the node?

Comment: When adding to a linked list, there is no such thing as a "temp" node. There is only the "added" node, and that's exactly what you have here. You should free *all* the nodes in your "System" (whatever that is) instance whenever its time to cleanup and/or otherwise manage your object.  That said, this could be done in about 1/5th this much code if you're really interested, And fyi, `if ([any of the constructors are invalid]) return 0;` should be done *before* `malloc`. If that does what it claims (just returns 0) that is *definitely* a leak.

Comment: There can be a function where system modules is deleted according to program logic where modules can be freed. Just free is not enough but Modules->text also has to be freed. If free causes segfault possibly temp is getting reassigned junk or unmalloced address in actual code which can be traced in actual code or using gdb.

Comment: @WhozCraig Your first sentence was actually super helpful. I guess I was thinking of temp as something that needed to be gotten rid of after I made a "copy" of it into the linkedlist, which I'm now seeing isn't really how it works. I rewrote a separate function that's supposed to clear everything to iterate through every member of each linked list and free the text field followed by the node itself, and I've fixed the memory leaks. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user11500789 Are you the least bit curious how to do that insertion function much *much* simpler ?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes please

Comment: @chux was a typo, fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your management of a `System` instance is sound (a big assumption, since I cannot see that code), you have giant hole in the memory allocation of `temp` with a subsequent hard `return 0` in the condition where the "constructor" check fails. More to the point:

```
Module *temp = malloc(sizeof(Module)); // memory allocated here...
Module *current;
temp->next = NULL;

if ([any of the constructors are invalid]) 
    return 0; // and leaked here.
```

It may be as simple as swapping the check around. Obviously other code that is supposed to free the dynamic allocations should be considered and evaluated as well.

---

**A Simpler Approach**

The node addition code is *complicated* and it need not be. In the end all you should really care about is finding the place where your new node resides.

1. If the slot in the table is empty, its the first node in that list.
2. IF the slot in the table is NOT empty, find the sorted location and insert it there.

*Both* of those can be accomplished with a single while-loop by using a pointer-to-pointer, where said entity hold the address of the pointer that will hold the new node in *either* of the cases above, and as a bonus, surgical insertion is literally two assignments.

It's done like this. Note that most of this code is just making the `Module` object safely. The actual insertion is only a single while-loop and some pointer assignments. It assumes the table in `System` initially contains NULL entries:

```
int addMod(System *system, const char *text, int num1, int num2, int index)
{
    // allocate new node here
    Module *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate new Module");
        return 0;
    }


    size_t len = strlen(text);
    temp->text = malloc(len + 1);
    if (temp->text == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate module name");
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }

    // finish copying member data
    memcpy(temp->text, text, len);
    temp->text[len] = 0;
    temp->num1 = num1;
    temp->num2 = num2;

    // now find where it belongs, and set next appropriately    
    Module **pp = system->modules + index;
    while (*pp && system->compare(temp, *pp) <= 0)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    temp->next = *pp;
    *pp = temp;
    return 1;
}
```

Understand this is from deriving what I *think* your `System` type looks like, as it was never presented:

```
typedef struct System
{
    Module *modules[MAX_MODULES];
    int (*compare)(const Module* lhs, const Module *rhs);

} System;
```

I'm fairly confident it is similar to this. Of course, you'll have to adapt if it isn't. I suggest you review this and step through it in a debugger. There is no substitute for watching it live.

Best of luck.

Comment: `int addMod()` needs a final `return`